# Vocatives Detection in Children Stories

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I would like to detect vocatives in different stories as a step of recognizing family relationship . Therefore, I need a vocatives corpus NLTK or some other source. I couldn't find one that I can use.

This should be a function which takes as input a file (which contains a text) and the output should be a dictionary which contains as key the addressee (e.g. sister) and as value all vocatives that belong to the addressee (e.g. dear, dearest, etc.)

Vocatives are for example:

> dear (sister), madam (Boente), little (sister), dearest (sister).

Is this possible without defining the vocatives as a white list? 
And can we automatize it through a corpus to reach our output?

Comment: Are you planning to include spoken corpora? Or what's behind the speech recognition tag?

Comment: @lenz I have used the tag because I am unsure which technique I should use to solve my problem. My text contains not only, but also spoken instances that's why I used the tag.

Comment: It's an interesting topic, but I doubt that there has been much work you can build upon. Also, this is much more of a research question than a programming problem. If you solve this, you can  submit a paper at a conference about it. But it's a bit too much for this site, I'm afraid.

Comment: could you paste some example text with the vocatives being marked?

Comment: Speech recognition is about processing audio recordings, not about transcribed dialog. The tag is a red herring.

Comment: What you want is coreference resolution narrowed down to vocatives. I don't have a solution to your problem but if you want a corpus with lots of such expressions in a child-directed speech register, you can check in the CHILDES collection of child and parent speech. Some subcorpora might even be annotated with what you want. The nltk provides an interface, but you have to select and download the corpora yourself from the [CHILDES website](http://childes.psy.cmu.edu/)

Comment: You can't just use a "white list". Expressions like "My friend" or "Madam Boente" could be vocatives or could just refer to a third person. You need some real nlp for this.

Comment: @alexis, how do you know the "spoken instances" are transcribed dialog, not audio recordings?

Comment: First, the OP refers to the input (twice) as "a text"; second, if it really was about audio it would be clear that [speech-recognition] is an appropriate tag. (And third, even if the goal was to deal with audio data, it would be a separate issue from recognizing vocative syntax.)